# GSM encoded WAV files in browser

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, audio

Good day!

I develop a website using Ruby-on-Rails and Jquery. This site has a feature to play files from an IVR system right in browser window, without downloading it. These files are in non-PCM WAV format, exactly GSM format. So I can't use standard audio tag solution. I tried to use some additional JS libraries, like audio.js and howler.js, but no luck.

What should I use to play these files in modern browsers? I think, that there are solutions of this problem, but I can't find it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You will need to convert on the server side or try to find Flash based player that supports GSM

Answer (score 1):

Since GSM is not supported on any browser ( [see this table](http://html5doctor.com/html5-audio-the-state-of-play/#support)) you will need to convert it before.

Now you have two options, you can convert on-the-fly or convert any files you already have and will converting the new ones as they are created.

You can use ffmpeg to do the job, with [streamio-ffmpeg gem](https://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg) or you can also find a SaaS solution for the job.