# GSM extension not playing on Web browser

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm trying to play a audio file with (.gsm) extension, I tried with `<audio>` and `object` tags, as well as using js.

```
<script>
var myAudio = new Audio();        // create the audio object
myAudio.src = "test.gsm"; // assign the audio file to its src
myAudio.play();                   // play the music
</script>
```

but nothing resulted good. So how can I play `.gsm` extension on-the-go on a web page?

Comment: What is the filetype `.gsm`? Have you checked if it's supported by the browsers?

Comment: Have you looked at [this question, which is similar to yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28698526/gsm-encoded-wav-files-in-browser)?

Comment: yes @evolutionxbox i tried searching it, but nothing went good.

Comment: I think your option is to convert the file into one that is supported by browsers, like `.mp3`.

Comment: yes @evolutionxbox but that should be done on-the-go.

Comment: Is this resolved I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It will never work without  GSM codec. you'll need to grab one mega Codec pack contains GSM 6.10 http://www.free-codecs.com/ace_mega_codecs_pack_download.htm

Html 5 audio will only support:
MP3 audio/mpeg 
Ogg audio/ogg 
Wav audio/wav

Comment: the link took me to 404.

Comment: try now. i've udpated url

Comment: yup tried, thanks for the update.
could you please brief on it, saying a step wise procedure.!
thanks for the response.

Comment: In case of Linux OS?